# Load JQuery async using JHtml in Joomla?

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, joomla3.0

Our current Joomla template uses `<jdoc:include type="head" />` to load jquery and a few other scripts on each page. Some of the scripts I believe are being loaded by the JHtml class in libraries/cms/html/jquery.php.

Below is the code where I found the reference to the scripts in jquery.php.

Is there anyway I can tell Joomla to load these scripts asynchronously using the current JHtml method?

```
public static function framework($noConflict = true, $debug = null, $migrate = true)
{
    // Only load once
    if (!empty(static::$loaded[__METHOD__]))
    {
        return;
    }

    // If no debugging value is set, use the configuration setting
    if ($debug === null)
    {
        $config = JFactory::getConfig();
        $debug  = (boolean) $config->get('debug');
    }

    JHtml::_('script', 'jui/jquery.min.js', false, true, false, false, $debug);

    // Check if we are loading in noConflict
    if ($noConflict)
    {
        JHtml::_('script', 'jui/jquery-noconflict.js', false, true, false, false, false);
    }

    // Check if we are loading Migrate
    if ($migrate)
    {
        JHtml::_('script', 'jui/jquery-migrate.min.js', false, true, false, false, $debug);
    }

    static::$loaded[__METHOD__] = true;

    return;
}
```

Comment: This is the `framework` function which imports jQuery only. You need to loop for the `script` function and you're answer should be found there

Comment: @Lodder Could you provide some more context for this? Or point me to some documentation for the script and framework functions? In looking for an answer, I've seen people suggest creating a plugin that loops through the array that holds all of the head scripts. Are you suggesting something like that or is there a better way?

Comment: See my answer on Joomla Stack Exchange from a while back: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/add-javascript-with-doc-addscript-with-async-true